# Unable to comprehend Java calling method on method

Tags: java

So I am reading up on Java and I came across an example. I have no idea how it works. Below you will see the method `sortByTime()` in the `ConsLoRunner` class. My question is how is it able to output something, wouldn't it just recurse that method over and over again, and never reach the `insertByTime(this.first)` method?

Side Note: The example is of Runners for a marathon and sorting them based on their times (fastest to slowest).

```
class Runner {
    String name;
    int age;
    int bib;
    boolean isMale;
    int pos;
    int time;

    Runner(String name, int age, int bib, boolean isMale, int pos, int time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.bib = bib;
        this.isMale = isMale;
        this.pos = pos;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public boolean finishesBefore(Runner r) {
        return this.time < r.time;
    }
}

interface ILoRunner {
    ILoRunner sortByTime();
    ILoRunner insertByTime(Runner r);
}

class MtLoRunner implements ILoRunner {

    public ILoRunner sortByTime() {
        return this;
    }

    public ILoRunner insertByTime(Runner r) {
        return new ConsLoRunner(r, this);
    }

}

class ConsLoRunner implements ILoRunner {
    Runner first;
    ILoRunner rest;

    ConsLoRunner(Runner first, ILoRunner rest) {
        this.first = first;
        this.rest = rest;
    }
    /*******HOW DOES IT DO THIS?????**********/
    public ILoRunner sortByTime() {
        return this.rest.sortByTime().insertByTime(this.first);
    }

    public ILoRunner insertByTime(Runner r) {
        if (this.first.finishesBefore(r)) {
            return new ConsLoRunner(this.first, this.rest.insertByTime(r));
        }
        else {
            return new ConsLoRunner(r, this);
        }
    }
}

class ExamplesRunners {
    MtLoRunner empty = new MtLoRunner();
    Runner tim = new Runner ("Tim", 1, 2, true, 5, 6);
    Runner bob = new Runner ("Bob", 5, 6, true, 9, 50);
    Runner jim = new Runner ("Jim", 5, 6, true, 10, 40);

    ILoRunner list1 = new ConsLoRunner(this.tim, new ConsLoRunner(this.bob, new ConsLoRunner(this.jim, this.empty)));

    boolean testSort(Tester t) {
        return t.checkExpect(this.list1.sortByTime(), new ConsLoRunner(this.tim, new ConsLoRunner(this.jim, new ConsLoRunner(this.bob, this.empty))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no idea how it works.

I'll try to answer this.

You are looking at a (pretty confusing) Java version of the [List Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)), which is usually found in languages like [LISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)).

A "list" in our case can be defined recursively. It is either:

- A empty list, denoted by `()` or `nil`, or
- The first element followed by another list (the rest of the elements): `(first, rest)`

As you can see, there's a clear mapping of your Java classes to these concepts:

```
ILoRunner    -> An abstract List, the root type
MtLoRunner   -> An empty list: () or nil
ConsLoRunner -> A non-empty list: (first, rest)
```

*The clue is in the beginning of the name `ConsLoRunner`. In LISP, `cons` is a "constructor" that creates an object holding another two objects. `cons` is often used to create lists. But it can also be used to create non-list structures. Sorry, I digress.*

Rewriting your example into a list representation, the list of runners `list1` looks roughly like this (omitting other fields for simplicity):

```
(Tim  <-- first: Tim, rest: (Bob ...)
    (Bob <-- first: Bob, rest: (Jim ())
        (Jim ()))) <-- first: Jim, rest: () // rest of the list is empty, no more elements.
```

Exactly what `ExamplesRunners` is doing.

Now for the confusing part. The code is sorting the runners by their finish time. The idea is pretty simple, to sort a list like this, we

1. First sort the rest of the list
2. Then insert the first element into the sorted list in step one

This is what `ConsLoRunner.sortByTime` is doing. But notice that it's returning a new, sorted list. **So the original list is never changed.**

To insert an element `x` into a sorted list is also simple:

1. Compare `x` with the first element of the list
2. If `x` is smaller, insert `x` before the whole list
3. Otherwise, insert `x` into the rest of the list

Bear in mind that insertion is done by creating a new `cons` object, with the appropriate order of elements. Again, the original list is preserved.

IMO, the code would be much easier to read if it were written against the actual list interface, instead of mixed together with the internal representation and construction of new lists.

```
// The list interface
interface List<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    boolean isEmpty();

    T first();

    List<T> rest();
}

// Instances of this class represents an empty list: ()
class Empty<T extends Comparable<T>> implements List<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T first() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> rest() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "()";
    }
}

// A non-empty list, composed of the first element and the rest.
class Cons<T extends Comparable<T>> implements List<T> {

    private final T first;
    private final List<T> rest;

    public Cons(T first, List<T> rest) {
        this.first = first;
        this.rest = rest;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T first() {
        return first;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> rest() {
        return rest;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + first +", " + rest + ")";
    }
}

public class Lisp {

    // Creates and returns a sorted list from the given list
    // The original list is never changed.
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> sort(List<T> list) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            // Empty lists are already sorted.
            return list;
        } else {
            // We first sort the rest of the list
            List<T> sortedRest = sort(list.rest());
            // Then insert the first element into the sorted list
            return insert(list.first(), sortedRest);
        }
    }

    // Creates and returns a sorted list with x inserted into a proper position in the already sorted list
    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> insert(T x, List<T> list) {
        if (list.isEmpty() || x.compareTo(list.first()) < 0) {
            return new Cons<>(x, list);
        } else {
            // Recursive call return a sorted list containing x
            return new Cons<>(list.first(),
                              insert(x, list.rest()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List<Integer> alist = new Cons<>(7, new Cons<>(1, new Cons<>(4, new Empty<>())));
        System.out.println("Sorted:   " + sort(alist));
        System.out.println("Original: " + alist);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Sorted:   (1, (4, (7, ())))
Original: (7, (1, (4, ())))
```

Comment: This was amazing thank you so very much. One part I'm still confused about is how does Java know to `1. Sort the rest of the list`. All you're doing is calling a method on the rest of the list? How does it magically just sort it?

Comment: Ah that's the beauty of recursion, right? You first define the base case for the empty list. Then in each recursion you give the method a smaller problem and assume the solution it gives you back is correct, then act on the solution to get a larger solution. I'll try to explain it better. :)

Answer (score 0):

> wouldn't it just recurse that method over and over again

No, it's not using recursion at all because it's calling a method on the class member `rest`:

return this.**rest**.sortByTime().insertByTime(this.first);

Comment: And if it's not using recursion what is the point of putting `.sortByTime()` in the return statement?

Comment: Please [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) for information about variables. The point of using `sortByTime()` in the return is to invoke that method, presumably to sort the data contained in that object, before returning a result.